# Customizing a zsh shell

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I am trying to modify my terminal by following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/how-to-customize-your-command-prompt/comment-page-1/).

But I can't seem to copy the `batchange.py` file to my `$PATH`, I tried `cp batchange.py ~/.bin` and everything else I can think of.Here is my $PATH: 
`'/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems‌​/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/‌​Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11‌​/bin:/usr/local/git/bin' –`

Comment: What is your `$PATH`? (`echo $PATH`). By default, `~/.bin` isn't in the `PATH` - you'd have to [add it](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=407157).

Comment: '/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin'

Comment: You're better off editing the question to include that information, rather than the comments - it's much easier for people to notice and read if it's all in the one place. :) You don't have `~/.bin` in your path. I'll stick an answer up.

Comment: I am a noob when it comes to bash and zsh ( which I just installed to do the tutorial ) does my $PATH seem a little.. messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add `~/bin` to your path:**

1. First, we make the folder (if it isn't already made).

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. Copy `batcharge.py` into `~/bin`:

   ```
   cp batcharge.py ~/bin/batcharge.py
   ```

   (Obviously you'll want to do this from where-ever the `batcharge.py` script is located).
3. Check if `~/bin` is in your path:

   ```
   echo $PATH | grep ~/bin
   ```

   This should come back with a line. If it does *not*, we shall add it:

   1. Open `~/.zshrc`.
   2. At the end, add the line:

      ```
      export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
      ```

      This will add `~/bin` to your `$PATH`.
   3. Close the terminal window, and re-open it. (Or open a new one).
   4. Type `echo $PATH | grep ~/bin`. This should now show a line (and you should see `~/bin` at the end of the long-ish list of paths).
4. Now, we test: you should be able to type `which batcharge.py` and see that `zsh` knows where to find it. For example, type `which batcharge.py` in terminal, and you should see something like:

   ```
   /Users/simont/bin/batcharge.py
   ```

   Now we can type `batcharge.py` and see the script run :)

Comment: All I want to do is have the batchange.py to be in the path like this:'~/bin/batcharge.py' do I make a bin folder ( don't know why I added the . ) and then do export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/batchange.py

Comment: I really appreciate your help

Comment: Is this what my .zshrc file should look like ?# Customize to your needs...
export PATH=/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/batchange.py

Comment: Remove the period (`.`) from the `export PATH=$PATH:~/.bin` line, and that looks fairly good.

Comment: Okay I copied the file batchange.py into the folder bin. Here is my $PATH now '/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/anthonybrown/bin/batchange.py' But it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: Ok. What about it doesn't seem to be working? It's in `~/bin` (run `ls ~/bin`)? Does `which batcharge.py` return anything? Your `$PATH` looks good; you could possibly try making it executable (run `chmod +x ~/bin/batcharge.py`). *IF* all of those things work, then you should check that the script is written properly (specifically check the lines near the bottom that look like `color_green = '%{[32m%}'` -- those lines will **NOT** copy well from a browser, so you should check the script has them correct and edit them if necessary.

Comment: My mistake, I was calling it by the wrong name, instead of batchange.py it's batcharge.py. working now, thanks so much~!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11713/discussion-between-pixel-67-and-simont)